# deploying a java application on eclipse juno using jboss 7.1.0 server

Tags: java, deployment, jboss7.x

I am deploying a java application on eclipse juno using jboss 7.1.0 server.
Below is the problem i am encountering.Please help me with this.

```
532 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015010: 
The deployment scanner found a directory named META-INF that was not inside a directory whose name ends 
with .ear, .jar, .rar, .sar or .war. This is likely the result of unzipping an archive directly inside 
the C:\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments directory, which is a user error. The META-INF 
directory will not be scanned for deployments, but it is possible that the scanner mayfind other files 
from the unzipped archive and attempt to deploy them, 
leading to errors.


532 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015010: 
The deployment scanner found a directory named WEB-INF that was not inside a directory whose name ends 
with .ear, .jar, .rar, .sar or .war. This is likely the result of unzipping an archive directly inside 
the C:\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments directory, which is a user error. The WEB-INF
directory will not be scanned for deployments, but it is possible that the scanner mayfind other files 
from the unzipped archive and attempt to deploy them, leading to errors.
```

Answer (score 4):

try to delete all files and folders inside C:\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments  and try again.