# jasper server war deployment over jboss getting failed

Tags: jboss, jasperserver

I am trying to deploy jaserserver war on jsboss but its getting failded
war putted at location  @location

```
 `D:\Software\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
```

jboss server log Server

```
      15:18:24,371 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Cont*roller Boot Thread) JBAS01461
2: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "jasperserver.war")]) - failure descrip
tion: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.m
odule.jasperserver.jasperserver.env.jdbc.jasperserver is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.jas
perserver]"]}*
```

I any clue what is going wrong ? i am running jboss server using  standalone.bat (run as a administrator )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deploying a java application on eclipse juno using jboss 7.1.0 server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685011/deploying-a-java-application-on-eclipse-juno-using-jboss-7-1-0-server)

Comment: @AlexK I am running through using command line .I am not using eclipse.

Comment: @AlexK i have deleted and re-deployed war got different error .It says few jar are missing but i checked it was there.